# При добавлении кириллических данных в базу отображаются иероглифы

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, h2

При добавлении кириллических данных в базу отображаются иероглифы. База данных H2. Везде где можно поставил кодировку `UTF-8`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "application.repo")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "application")
public class DataServiceConfig {
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        try {
            return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder().setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).addScripts("classpath:db/shema.sql",
                    "classpath:db/insert.sql").build();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProp = new Properties();
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
//        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.format_sql", true);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.use_sql_comments", true);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.max_fetch_depth", 3);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", 10);
        hibernateProp.put("hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size", 50);
        return hibernateProp;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("application.entities");
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        factoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return factoryBean.getNativeEntityManagerFactory();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory());
    }
}
```

class SingerController

```
package application.web;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/singers")
public class SingerController {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SingerController.class);
    private SingerService singerService;
    private MessageSource messageSource;

    @Autowired
    public void setSingerService(SingerService singerService) {
        this.singerService = singerService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMessageSource(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String list(Model uiModel){
        log.info("listing singers");
        List<Singer> singers = singerService.findAll();
        uiModel.addAttribute("singers" , singers);
        log.info("No. of singers: "+ singers.size());
        return "singers/list";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String show(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel){
        log.info("просмотр певца по id {}", id);
        Singer singer = singerService.findById(id);
        uiModel.addAttribute("singer", singer);
        log.info("певец найден");
        return "singers/show";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String update(@Valid Singer singer, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
                         RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes, Locale locale){
        log.info("Updating singer");
        if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
            uiModel.addAttribute("message", new Message("error", messageSource.getMessage("singer_save_fail",
                    new Object[]{}, locale)));
            uiModel.addAttribute("singer", singer);
            return "singers/update";
        }
        uiModel.asMap().clear();
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", new Message("success", messageSource.getMessage("singer_save_success",
                new Object[]{}, locale)));
        singerService.save(singer);
        return "redirect:/singers/" + UrlUtil.encodeUrlPathSegment(singer.getId().toString(), httpServletRequest);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", params = "form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String updateForm(@PathVariable("id") Long id, Model uiModel){
        uiModel.addAttribute("singer", singerService.findById(id));
        return "singers/update";
    }
}
```

class WebConfig

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"application"})
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Bean
    ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setBasenames("WEB-INF/i18n/messages", "WEB-INF/i18n/application");
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setFallbackToSystemLocale(false);
        return messageSource;
    }

    @Bean
    ResourceBundleThemeSource themeSource() {
        return new ResourceBundleThemeSource();
    }

    @Bean
    ThemeChangeInterceptor themeChangeinterceptor() {
        return new ThemeChangeInterceptor();
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(localeChangeInterceptor());
        registry.addInterceptor(themeChangeinterceptor());
    }

    @Bean
    LocaleChangeInterceptor localeChangeInterceptor() {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor interceptor = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        interceptor.setParamName("lang");
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    CookieLocaleResolver localeResolver() {
        CookieLocaleResolver cookieLocaleResolver = new CookieLocaleResolver();
        cookieLocaleResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieMaxAge(3600);
        cookieLocaleResolver.setCookieName("locale");
        return cookieLocaleResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    CookieThemeResolver themeResolver() {
        CookieThemeResolver cookieThemeResolver = new CookieThemeResolver();
        cookieThemeResolver.setDefaultThemeName("standard");
        cookieThemeResolver.setCookieMaxAge(3600);
        cookieThemeResolver.setCookieName("theme");
        return cookieThemeResolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("singers/list");
    }

    @Bean
    UrlBasedViewResolver tilesViewResolver() {
        UrlBasedViewResolver tilesViewResolver = new UrlBasedViewResolver();
        tilesViewResolver.setViewClass(TilesView.class);
        return tilesViewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer() {
        TilesConfigurer tilesConfigurer = new TilesConfigurer();
        tilesConfigurer.setDefinitions(
                "/WEB-INF/layouts/layouts.xml",
                "/WEB-INF/views/singers/views.xml"
        );
        tilesConfigurer.setCheckRefresh(true);
        return tilesConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean
    public DateFormatter dateFormatter(){
        return new DateFormatter();
    }

    @Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry formatterRegistry){
        formatterRegistry.addFormatter(dateFormatter());
    }
}
```

class WebInitializer

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
            DataServiceConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{
                WebConfig.class
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }

    @Override
    protected Filter[] getServletFilters() {
        CharacterEncodingFilter cef = new CharacterEncodingFilter();
        cef.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        cef.setForceEncoding(true);
        return new Filter[]{new HiddenHttpMethodFilter(), cef};
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Кодировка символов в HTTP запросах и ответах в `spring-webmvc`

См. метод [`extendMessageConverters`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html#extendMessageConverters-java.util.List-) из интерфейса `WebMvcConfigurer`:

> A hook for extending or modifying the list of converters after it has been configured. This may be useful for example to allow default converters to be registered and then insert a custom converter through this method.

т. е. стандартный набор конвертеров можно дополнить своими, или изменить существующие:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.forEach(converter -> {
            if (converter instanceof AbstractHttpMessageConverter) {
                ((AbstractHttpMessageConverter) converter).setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                if (converter instanceof StringHttpMessageConverter) {
                    ((StringHttpMessageConverter) converter).setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
                }
            } else if (converter instanceof FormHttpMessageConverter) {
                ((FormHttpMessageConverter) converter).setCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                ((FormHttpMessageConverter) converter).setMultipartCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            }
        });
    }
}
```